# Reading values from Excel workbook in every worksheet in particular column

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'd like to read the values from column B in every worksheet within my workbook.

After a fair amount of reading and playing around I can return the cell names of the cells I want the values from, but I can't figure out how to get the values.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(r"C:/Users/username/Documents/test.xlsx")
for sheet in wb.worksheets:
    for row in range(2,sheet.max_row+1):
        for column in "B":
            cell_name = "{}{}".format(column, row)
            print (cell_name)
```

This is returning the cell names (i.e. B2, B3) that have values in column B in every worksheet.

Comment: You r close try a bit more you will get it.

Comment: I have tried quite a lot - that's why I had that I'm a beginner in the question (which got deleted for an unknown reason). I have changed the print to:  print (sheet['cell_name'].value) but its not a valid coordinate

Comment: `for column in "B":` is just iterating over only one value "B", you can removed that inner loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import xlrd

loc = ("foo.xlsx")  # excel file name
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
# sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

for sheet in wb.sheets():
    for i in range(sheet.nrows):
        print(sheet.cell_value(i, 1))
```

Edit: I edited my answer to read all sheets in excel file.

Comment: That only returns one sheets values, it needs to be every sheet

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html you can access cell values as:

```
sheet['B5'].value
```

Replace B5 with the cell(s) you need.

Comment: And `sheet['B']` gives you the whole column.

Answer (score 0):

just play with the range

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('')
for sheet in wb:
    for i in range(1,50):
        if sheet['B'+str(i)].value:
            print(sheet['B'+str(i)].value)
```

Better one,

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('')
for sheet in wb:
    for row in sheet['B']:
        print(row.value)
```